# MainActivity reconhece métodos de classes externas

Tags: android-studio, classes

E aii galera, estou começando a programar com Android Studio, mas estou com um problema. Criei uma classe no mesmo pacote do MainActivity, e consegui instânciar essa classe, mas não consigo utilizar os Métodos dela. O MainActivity não esá reconhecendo esses métodos.

**Segue Código da Classe:**

```
package com.example.myapplication;

public class Casa {

    public void AbrirPorta(){
        System.out.println("Porta Aberta");
    }
}
```

**Segue Código MainActivity:**

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    Casa C = new Casa();
}
```

Comment: Boa noite, Wesley! Onde você  chama o método?

Comment: sim Ivan, logo depois da instância, eu chamo a classe, mas não sugere nenhuma opção dos métodos. E se eu digitar o nome do método, ele não é reconhecido

Answer (score 1):

Boa noite, Wesley!

Simplesmente chame seu método dentro de outro, dessa forma

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Casa c = new Casa(); // Mudei de posição apenas por questões didáticas

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Chame aqui ou dentro de outro método
        c.seuMetodo();
    }
}
```

No espaço interno da classe, você pode apenas declarar propriedades/parâmetros, métodos e instanciar objetos [como você fez], mas não será possível fazer chamada à métodos.

Comment: Vlw Ivan, funcionou, mas o foda é que, segundo o instrutor do curso que estou fazendo, a chamada de método que ele faz funciona fora do "protected void onCreate()"

Comment: Não necessariamente precisar ser dentro do `onCreate`, mas precisa ser dentro de algum método. Se a minha resposta te ajudou, marca como correta. Abraço!

Comment: Qualquer coisa, pede pra ele provar que consegue chamar algum método dentro do "escopo" de outro